# Applying HAVING clause condition depending on a column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get some records from a table:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) < n.dailyshow
```

`n.dailyshow` is a number or letter (like `u`)

When `n.dailyshow = 'u'`, it means unlimited, and the `Having Count(*) < n.dailyshow` must be removed or something by `IF`, and when it's a number let the command stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
having if(n.dailyshow = 'u', true, (count(*) < n.dailyshow))
```

or

```
having n.dailyshow = 'u' or (count(*) < n.dailyshow)
```